# Loop through either Pandas dataframe or Excel Sheet with Python

Tags: python, excel

I want to preface this that I am VERY new to Python so I am very much learning as I go.

**Project:**

Scrape data from an HTML table, clean the data up and append to a copied template in Excel for a shipping report.

**Current Code:**

In my first step I get the data via:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
  

#Get order number for API call and create dataframe
wb = xw.books.active
sheet = wb.sheets['Variables']
OrderNum = str(sheet.range('B2').value)
Filepath = sheet.range('B1').value

OrderNum = OrderNum[:-2]

url = "https://extrnlnet.se.com/OrderStatusReport/ORDERPRINT.aspx?Print=EbaseOrderInquiry&OrderNumber={}&PurchID=21510&UserID=21510".format(OrderNum)
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

I then create a sheet to dump the data into, copy my template and rename it:
`

```
if OrderNum not in wb.sheet_names:
        wb.sheets.add(OrderNum)

#create sheet named the same as the order number and paste dataframe if sheet does not already exist

if '{} Report'.format(OrderNum) not in wb.sheet_names:
        ws = wb.sheets[OrderNum]
        ws.range('A1').options(index=False).value = df
        
        #copy report template to begin processing   
        ws = wb.sheets['ReportTemplate']
        ws.copy(name="{} Report".format(OrderNum))

#set worksheet to created page
ws = wb.sheets['{} Report'.format(OrderNum)]
#set secondary worksheet to pasted dataframe
ws1 = wb.sheets['{}'.format(OrderNum)]
```

`
Here is a snip of the data that gets dumped (cut a couple columns to reduce pictures width):
[image: sample data]

Column G is my "control" column. If the value `<>` "cancelled" I want to append specific columns to my empty copy of the template I just created.

**Problem:**
How would I properly loop through column "G" and append the rows specific columns when the value of column "G" does not equal "Cancelled"? Also, is it best/faster/easier to do dump the data into Excel and do this or should it be done while still in the dataframe?

I have read [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) but to be honest, a lot of that went over my head.

I could likely do this with VBA and construct a `For Each` loop, but as a challenge and learning experience I want to try and do this all within Python.

EDIT 1:

If column "G" (within excel) or header "Progress Point" in the dataframe has a value of "Cancelled", I want to delete/remove the entire row. There are also 6 columns from the HTML table that I do not need and would also need to delete/remove from the data frame.

Once the data frame is "cleaned up" doing the above, I would then write it to my Excel report.

Here is the ["raw"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLiuw.png) data and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I00e4.png) would be the desired output. Several columns were removed along with rows that had the progress point of cancelled.

Comment: I am not shure what you are trying to achieve. Could you break it down a little more?

Comment: Not sure what you exaclty meant with "append the rows specific columns". What i can say is yo ushould definitely use Pandas instead of excel. Once you'll be done with all the processing, you can then transform to Excel (via pandas.DataFrame.to_excel() (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html))

Comment: I will add more clarification to my question. Please give me a moment.

Comment: Added more clarification and 2 pictures of the base data and desired output (as best as i could describe it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you are trying to do two things:

1. You want to delete rows in the table, based on the "Progress Point" column:

   ```
   df = df[df['Progress Point] != 'Cancelled']
   ```

   (Get only columns where the value of 'Progress Point' is not 'Cancelled')
2. You want to drop columns you don't need:

   ```
   columns_to_drop = ['Line Nbr', 'Total Qty'] # add columns here
   df = df.drop(columns=columns_to_drop)
   ```

After this you can write the data to Excel with:

```
df.to_excel(path_to_file, sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

Have a look at the documentation:

[pd.DataFrame.drop()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

[pd.DataFrame.to_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Do yourself a favor and get familiar with pandas. You don't need xlwings or openpyxl. You can get the OrderNumber from Excel with pandas.read_excel().

Comment: I will read up more on pandas. When researching how to initially begin this project, xlwings was the library I kept seeing being recommended when Excel was involved. Other than that, your answer worked beautifully and will let me continue on. Thank you!